# Generating and using many images failure

Tags: image, opencv

I'm having a problem when trying to manipulate a great number of images. I can run the algorithm if this number is low, but it doesn't work when I run it with a great number of images.

So, I have 12 images, and I need to generate 288 more from those images. I can generate the first set of 288 images from the first one and the second set from the second image. But after that, the program stops and then I got the following error:

"mm_areaopen: lib failed"

Here is the code where the algorithm stops:

```
for (int n = 0; n < 3; n++){

    // tecido Normal -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    str_normal.str("");
    title_normal.clear();
    str_normal << "normal-" << n + 1 << ".tif";
    title_normal = str_normal.str();
    normal = title_normal.c_str();

    original_normal = cvLoadImage(normal, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    image_names[i] = normal;

    str_normal.str("");
    title_normal.clear();
    str_normal << "normal-" << n + 1 << "-selection" << ".tif";
    title_normal = str_normal.str();
    normal = title_normal.c_str();

    goldStandard_normal = imread(normal, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    // tecido NIC-1 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    str_nic1.str("");
    title_nic1.clear();
    str_nic1 << "nic1-" << n + 1 << ".tif";
    title_nic1 = str_nic1.str();
    nic1 = title_nic1.c_str();

    original_nic1 = cvLoadImage(nic1, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    image_names[i] = nic1;

    str_nic1.str("");
    title_nic1.clear();
    str_nic1 << "nic1-" << n + 1 << "-selection" << ".tif";
    title_nic1 = str_nic1.str();
    nic1 = title_nic1.c_str();

    goldStandard_nic1 = imread(nic1, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    // tecido NIC-2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    str_nic2.str("");
    title_nic2.clear();
    str_nic2 << "nic2-" << n + 1 << ".tif";
    title_nic2 = str_nic2.str();
    nic2 = title_nic2.c_str();

    original_nic2 = cvLoadImage(nic2, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    image_names[i] = nic2;

    str_nic2.str("");
    title_nic2.clear();
    str_nic2 << "nic2-" << n + 1 << "-selection" << ".tif";
    title_nic2 = str_nic2.str();
    nic2 = title_nic2.c_str();

    goldStandard_nic2 = imread(nic2, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    // tecido NIC-3 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

    str_nic3.str("");
    title_nic3.clear();
    str_nic3 << "nic3-" << n + 1 << ".tif";
    title_nic3 = str_nic3.str();
    nic3 = title_nic3.c_str();

    original_nic3 = cvLoadImage(nic3, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    image_names[i] = nic3;

    str_nic3.str("");
    title_nic3.clear();
    str_nic3 << "nic3-" << n + 1 << "-selection" << ".tif";
    title_nic3 = str_nic3.str();
    nic3 = title_nic3.c_str();

    goldStandard_nic3 = imread(nic3, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++){

        j = 0;

        // tecido Normal -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

        if (i >= 0 && i < 3){

            for (p1 = 18; p1 <= 23; p1++){
                for (p2 = 1; p2 <= 3; p2++){
                    for (p3 = 1; p3 <= 4; p3++){
                        for (p4 = 100; p4 <= 175; p4 = p4 + 25){

                            parameterSet[j].p1 = p1;
                            parameterSet[j].p2 = p2;
                            parameterSet[j].p3 = p3;
                            parameterSet[j].p4 = p4;

                            parameterSet[j].media = 0;

                            j++;

                            watershedImage_normal = Morphology::doPipeline(original_normal, p1, p2, p3, p4);
                            img_normal = watershedImage_normal;

                            cv::floodFill(img_normal, cvPoint(50, 50), cvScalar(255, 255, 255));
                            bitwise_not(img_normal, img_normal);

                            str_normal.str("");
                            title_normal.clear();
                            str_normal << "normal-" << n + 1 << "-" << p1 << "-" << p2 << "-" << p3 << "-" << p4 << ".tif";
                            title_normal = str_normal.str();

                            imwrite(title_normal, img_normal);

                            input_normal = imread(title_normal, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

                            parameterSet[j].overlap[i] = caib::areaOverlap(goldStandard_normal, input_normal);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // tecido NIC-1 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

        if (i >= 3 && i < 6){

            for (p1 = 18; p1 <= 23; p1++){
                for (p2 = 1; p2 <= 3; p2++){
                    for (p3 = 1; p3 <= 4; p3++){
                        for (p4 = 100; p4 <= 175; p4 = p4 + 25){

                            watershedImage_nic1 = Morphology::doPipeline(original_nic1, p1, p2, p3, p4);
                            img_nic1 = watershedImage_nic1;

                            cv::floodFill(img_nic1, cvPoint(50, 50), cvScalar(255, 255, 255));
                            bitwise_not(img_nic1, img_nic1);

                            str_nic1.str("");
                            title_nic1.clear();
                            str_nic1 << "nic1-" << n + 1 << "-" << p1 << "-" << p2 << "-" << p3 << "-" << p4 << ".tif";
                            title_nic1 = str_nic1.str();

                            imwrite(title_nic1, img_nic1);

                            input_nic1 = imread(title_nic1, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

                            parameterSet[j].overlap[i] = caib::areaOverlap(goldStandard_nic1, input_nic1);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }

        // tecido NIC-2 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

        if (i >= 6 && i < 9){

            for (p1 = 18; p1 <= 23; p1++){
                for (p2 = 1; p2 <= 3; p2++){
                    for (p3 = 1; p3 <= 4; p3++){
                        for (p4 = 100; p4 <= 175; p4 = p4 + 25){

                            watershedImage_nic2 = Morphology::doPipeline(original_nic2, p1, p2, p3, p4);
                            img_nic2 = watershedImage_nic2;

                            cv::floodFill(img_nic2, cvPoint(50, 50), cvScalar(255, 255, 255));
                            bitwise_not(img_nic2, img_nic2);

                            str_nic2.str("");
                            title_nic2.clear();
                            str_nic2 << "nic2-" << n + 1 << "-" << p1 << "-" << p2 << "-" << p3 << "-" << p4 << ".tif";
                            title_nic2 = str_nic2.str();

                            imwrite(title_nic2, img_nic2);

                            input_nic2 = imread(title_nic2, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

                            parameterSet[j].overlap[i] = caib::areaOverlap(goldStandard_nic2, input_nic2);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // tecido NIC-3 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------|

        if (i >= 9 && i < 12){

            for (p1 = 18; p1 <= 23; p1++){
                for (p2 = 1; p2 <= 3; p2++){
                    for (p3 = 1; p3 <= 4; p3++){
                        for (p4 = 100; p4 <= 175; p4 = p4 + 25){

                            watershedImage_nic3 = Morphology::doPipeline(original_nic3, p1, p2, p3, p4);
                            img_nic3 = watershedImage_nic3;

                            cv::floodFill(img_nic3, cvPoint(80, 80), cvScalar(255, 255, 255));
                            bitwise_not(img_nic3, img_nic3);

                            str_nic3.str("");
                            title_nic3.clear();
                            str_nic3 << "nic3-" << n + 1 << "-" << p1 << "-" << p2 << "-" << p3 << "-" << p4 << ".tif";
                            title_nic3 = str_nic3.str();

                            imwrite(title_nic3, img_nic3);

                            input_nic3 = imread(title_nic3, IMREAD_UNCHANGED);

                            parameterSet[j].overlap[i] = caib::areaOverlap(goldStandard_nic3, input_nic3);

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

After opening all the "nic1-1.tif" images, the error appears. Does anyone know why this is happening?

By the way, the Morphology::doPipeline method utilize the SDC Morphology Toolbox for C++ 1.6.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: You never call `cvReleaseImage()` although you are repeatedly allocating images with `cvLoadImage()`. Possibly you are running out of memory. Also you have a strange mix of the deprecated C API (e.g. IplImage's and cvLoadImage) and the proper C++ API (e.g. Mat's and imread).

Comment: Yes, but there is some methods that needs IplImage as parameters. How can I solve this memory problem?

Comment: Mat has an IplImage() operator so you can cast it to an IplImage (and without copying the data). I would wrap up the methods that need an IplImage so that it is easy to avoid leaks. If all your data is controlled by Mats, most of the memory issues will be handled transparently.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about that. I'll try using only Mat.

Comment: Didn't work, the operator works only for IplImage, but I need *IplImage =(

Comment: That's not a problem - I posted an answer to show one way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap up you legacy library like below. Note that you create an IplImage then pass the address of that for the function that needs an IplImage*

```
 cv::Mat myPipeline(cv::Mat original_nic, int p1, int p2, int p3, int p4)
 { 
     IplImage original_iplimage = IplImage(original_nic);
     IplImage* watershedImage = Morphology::doPipeline( & original_iplimage , p1, p2, p3, p4);
     cv::Mat result(watershedImage, true);
     cvReleaseImage(watershedImage);
     return result;
 }
```